# jQuery - Object declaration

Tags: javascript, jquery

I found the following jquery code pattern. I think it was chosen to structure the code in a better way. I was wondering because the object declaration has no 'var' or something. Is the code right?

JS

```
MyObject = (function() {


 return function() {
    alert("object created");
 };
})();

$(function() {
    new MyObject();
});
```

Comment: Is that the actual code? 'cause all that's going to do is throw an exception when the ready handler runs. `MyObject` is `undefined` after that first statement.

Comment: I found this code in the project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your comment, it sounds like that is the actual code you have and not a paraphrased version of it, so that's just some bogus code.

1. You can create a variable and assign a value to it without using `var` and it will be treated as a global variable, but this is considered a bad practice and forbidden in strict mode.
2. The first statement is an [IIFE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression), but it doesn't return anything, so `MyObject` is undefined. So when `new MyObject();` eventually runs, it will just throw an error and halt the execution of the ready handler.

It looks like the person who wrote that code *may* have been trying to do this, but was making an attempt to be clever:

```
var MyObject = function() {
    alert("Object created");
};

$(function() {
    new MyObject();
});
```

Here, `MyObject` is a function that shows an alert. The jQuery ready handler invokes that function as a constructor, which causes the code inside the function to run (showing an alert), and creating a new object. However, this object is not used or assigned anywhere, so it just gets garbage collected after some period of time.

Answer (score 0):

Using variable without var keyword is set to global scope. So, `MyObject` is equivalent to `window.MyObject` and you can it elsewhere in your script.